# Best auth strategy for GCP client tool

Tags: api, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I want to build a client gcp tool in python.

I want to avoid invocations of the `glcoud` tool via `subprocess` so I opt for sdk [client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python) invocations.

According to the docs as also [this](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-iam-listing-projects/) very and comprehensive article, there are two options for auth:

a) using the application default credentials (i.e. the ones used by `gcloud` under the hood)

b) using a service account and pointing the app to the corresponding `.json` file.

I have already tried the (a) and got the following warning:

> UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user
>   credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server
>   applications use service accounts instead. If your application
>   continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might
>   receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more
>   information about service accounts, see
>   https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
>   warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)

If I use app default creds, this makes it easy since each end user the app will be distributed to, will have this `.json` file a source of truth for his/her auth process. However, the app may encounter the above `quota exceeded` error.

In the other case, (service account specific credentials) I assume I will have to provide instructions to each developer to issue a json file that corresponds to a service account with the exact same permission as his/hers. And what about the update process? What happens each time a user gets assigned / revoked some permissions? How this json stays in sync?

Any advice about this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are several types of application default credentials (ADC): User Account and Service Account and variations of those. The warning message in your question means that you set up the SDK CLI with user account credentials (`gcloud auth login`). I recommend switching to service account credentials.

This command will setup the CLI with a service account. You will need your Project ID and service account JSON file.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account test@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service_account.json
```

I wrote an article that goes into detail on how to set up the CLI:

[Setting up Gcloud with Service Account Credentials](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/)

Why is Google giving you a warning:

- Authorizing User Credentials requires more effort on Google's backend services.
- User Account credentials require human interaction to create.
- The Refresh Token is often stored by software on the client or backends. This creates a security hole.
- Software should use machine-to-machine authentication with limited permissions (scopes). User credentials typically are issued with too many permissions for the API calls being made. This again is a security issue.
- Google has decided that User Credentials will not be allowed to have the scopes required to access many Google Cloud Platform services. This is very apparent when creating OAuth Clients and you receive a big warning about verification. There is a **strong risk** that Google will stop allowing user credentials for cloud services. It is better to use the supported and official method of a service account and not face this issue in the future.

However, given the above details, your use case is providing your users with credentials. This is not a good idea. I would continue to use User Credentials talking to your web frontend. Your web frontend uses a service account that the user never sees and provides the final service (API) access.

[UPDATE]

I just noticed your comment that you are developing your own CLI. Without more details on what projects/services this CLI will be accessing you might consider using user credentials that talk to your service which issues an Access Token to the user. This token is only valid for one hour. You can support refreshing this token in your code. This gives you the ability to use user authentication, control service account usage and still maintain good security. Notice that I am trying to steer you away from distributing service account files directly to users. If these users are your own employees, this is less of a problem. For people not under your control think carefully.

[END UPDATE]

I will try to provide details and advice on your questions. Do consider my previous comments while deciding the best strategy for you.

> In the other case, (service account specific credentials) I assume I
>   will have to provide instructions to each developer to issue a json
>   file that corresponds to a service account with the exact same
>   permission as his/hers.

If I were to write an application that used service account credentials, I would create a method to load/install the credentials. Just provide a file and tell them to do this step in the program. However, you have an issue. It is not a good idea to distribute the same service account to all users. How do you handle revoking, etc? Google Cloud Platform service accounts are not designed to be distributed uniquely to more than a few dozen or hundreds users per project.

> And what about the update process?

Service account credential JSON key files do not expire. The tokens created from the service account do expire but this is managed by Google client libraries or in your own code to automatically refresh them.

> What happens each time a user gets assigned/revoked some permissions?
>   How this JSON stay in sync?

The service account file does not contain permissions. These are stored in Google Cloud IAM. Once you modify the roles assigned to a service account, they are transparently applied globally within a few minutes.

Comment: thanks for the extended response. My main question is the following: Given that a) my requirement is that the cli tool reflects **exactly** the permissions that they (users/developers of the tool) either way have via `gcloud` b) I want them to be able to perform (a few) cross-project actions, such as `mycli list projects` how will the following command work since it requires a specific project id: `gcloud auth activate-service-account test@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=service_account.json
`

Comment: I am sure that there is a way around but I have to pass via my IT to interfere with IAM (so I want to minimise my boilerplate interaction the Gloud Console (ideally, even if the entire process is complex, I would like to have this initialization interaction via my python code).

Comment: e.g. for the time being, each dev can run `gcloud projects list` and they will get a list of projects they have access to. How can this be done api-wise (in terms of auth setup I mean)

Comment: So (sorry for the many posts) this makes me think: don't I actually want the **exact** same auth mechanism as `gcloud`? (which if I understand correctly are the application default credentials)

Comment: Let me also add to the topic this very interesting discussion (seems this is like an open debate and several other people are faced with same dilemmas as above) https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/issues/271

Comment: Please create separate questions. Stackoverflow is not a discussion forum. Most of your questions require longer answers than comments allow or would be valuable information for others. Most do not read the comments, just the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the tool is only expected to be used interactively (e.g. replacing gcloud), its likely fine to use the default credentials, as the usage will be low.

That said, creating a key for a service account is a pretty striaghtforward operation in either the console or via gcloud and the API makes it [reasonably easy to consume the key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/#examples) -- you basically set a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable.  See more at [this page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys).  Using service accounts also allows you to assign exactly the roles that are required, rather than operating with the broad permissions that a user account might have, and this reduces the possibility of mistakes where the code does something it shouldn't.

Comment: I see however that the service account keys are project-bound; this I assume will make tool operations such as `mytool list all-projects-I-have-access-to` difficult (if not impossible) via the specific mehod (?)

Comment: And yes the tool is going to be used **only** interactively as a cmd and kind of a `gcloud` replacement

Comment: You can grant service accounts outside the current project roles on that project.  See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479025/cross-project-management-using-service-account

Comment: The reason that the SDK CLI `gcloud` does not report a warning is that this tool is using a special OAuth Client ID. This client ID is whitelisted by Google. As I mentioned in my answer, Google Cloud Platform no longer wants you to use user credentials and is slowly making this more difficult. Eventually, I predict they will be dropped except for console access.