# How to discover the scope associated to my Google API credentials?

Tags: python, google-api, google-authentication

I'm using Google earthengine to run GIS computations. recently Google added projects to manages the created assets which means that I need to use the Google cloud API to find back my projet name.

I use a service account to connect to the API but for I don't manage to get access to my project list. I'm sure that I've add the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly" scope to my account though.

Is there a way for me to check using the API the list of my current scopes ?

```py
import ee 

ee.Iniitialize() 

# that's the credential I would like to test 
# it's a ServiceAccountCredential like any other Google API (I use it to connect to drive as well)
cred = ee.Credentials()

# something like 
for scope in cred.scopes(): 
    print(scope)
```

Comment: which api are you connecting to exactly can i get a documentation link that you are following for it?

Comment: I'm trying to complete the following workflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58366396/google-cloud-platform-list-available-projects-using-api and it's sytematically refused because of scope issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lookup access and identity tokens from Google's OAuth service `tokeninfo` method:

- `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token={access_token}`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token={id_token}`

And there's a Google CLI "OAuth tool" [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) that you find useful too.

It includes (among other things) an [`oauth2l info`](https://github.com/google/oauth2l#info) method